# Classes of Graphs used in Chemistry

Tags: one-topic-per-answer, molecular-modeling, mathematical-modeling

I am looking for common categories of graphs used in chemistry, for math research I am doing in graph theory.

When I write categories, the meaning is not for graphs design or types of design, but for categories of nature-originated large graphs (like large molecules), that can be mathematically described. For example, trees, unicyclic graphs, bipartite graphs, etc.

I mention it because I saw [a similar question on the Biology Stack Exhange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/84016/classes-of-graphs-used-in-biology), and the response there is not the meaning of the asker at all.

I tried to look for scientific articles that review it but did not find any related survey.

Comment: Well, typical chemist or biologist doesn't even know what graph theory is :( It's used pretty much only by guys bringing chemistry and maths together... and there's no tag for it ;)

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/11185/graph-theory-isomer-enumeration-and-chemical-graph-theory

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14491/molecular-connectivity-index https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134781/graph-representation-of-polymer-nanocomposites https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/122552/generating-molecular-graph-laplacian-based-on-h%c3%bcckel-theory

Comment: Graphs as an underlying concept to store and retrieve molecular geometries (incl. retrieve of sub-sturctures) in (reaction) databases like [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ci9005035) and [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00459)?

Comment: Outside of molecular geometries you might look at Diagrammatic Perturbation Theory,  Feynman diagrams being the best known. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41848/diagram-like-perturbation-theory-in-quantum-mechanics has a link that might be of interest

Comment: In biochemistry, there are graphs describing metabolic pathways.

Comment: For chemistry: a [book](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=X0AG7HhiccoC&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=graph+theory+biochemistry&ots=RbrtC8Vegz&sig=810btN-TJgZvLKo2ywzpwvQPVIU#v=onepage&q=graph%20theory%20biochemistry&f=false) and an [article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ci00047a033).

Comment: Another use of graph theory is in approximate solutions to the Ornstein-Zernike equation, which occurs in the theory of the structure of fluids

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1360/5

Comment: People in the community use molecular/structure/crystal graphs, in which the nodes are the atoms and edges are their connectivity. For example, see [here](https://pymatgen.org/pymatgen.analysis.graphs.html).

Answer (score 5):

#### Fullerene graphs

One example of a category of graphs that is used in chemistry is the set of [Fullerene graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fullerene.html). One Fullerene graph that is especially interesting to some chemists, is the [26-Fullerene graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/26-fullerene_graph). You may also be interested in [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00994783/document) about Fullerene graphs, or the book [An Atlas of Fullerenes](https://www.amazon.ca/Atlas-Fullerenes-P-W-Fowler/dp/0486453626)  by theoretical chemists Patrick Fowler and David Manolopoulos.

Answer (score 3):

### Hückel method can be related to Graph theory

Graph theory is not part of the average Chemistry undergraduate curriculum, so I have just cursory knowledge about it. But from what I read about, it shows everywhere in Chemistry. Regarding Matter Modeling, [Hückel molecular orbital theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel_method) is one of the early wins of quantitative theoretical chemistry, developed by [Erich Hückel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_H%C3%BCckel) in the 1930s, to explain systems containing conjugated double bonds that show up a lot in organic chemistry. For a bit of history on it, see (1). [Benzene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene) is the poster child of these systems.

Hückel proposed the energy levels in these systems can be obtained by solving a secular determinant with this form:

$$det([H_{ij} - ES_{ij}]) = 0$$

Where $H_{ij}$ and $S_{ij}$ are known as the overlap and Hamiltonian matrices. To solve it, he adopted the following approximations:

$$S_{ij} = 1,\text{ if } i = j$$
$$S_{ij} = 0,\text{ if } i \neq j$$
$$H_{ij} = \alpha,\text{ if } i = j$$
$$H_{ij} = \beta,\text{ if } i \text{ adjacent to } j$$
$$H_{ij} = 0,\text{ otherwise}$$

Where $\alpha$ is approximately the energy of a electron in a $2p_z$ isolated carbon orbital, and $\beta$ approximately the interaction energy of parallel $2p_z$ orbitals in adjacent carbons.

Taking the example of benzene, we obtain this:

[image]

Then we can use a computer algebra system (CAS) like [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to solve this secular determinant:

```
from sympy import symbols, Matrix, roots

E, α, β = symbols('E α β')
M = Matrix([[α-E,β,0,0,0,β],
            [β,α-E,β,0,0,0],
            [0,β,α-E,β,0,0],
            [0,0,β,α-E,β,0],
            [0,0,0,β,α-E,β],
            [β,0,0,0,β,α-E]])
benzene_polynomial = M.det()
benzene_roots = roots(benzene_polynomial, E)
print('Solutions:', benzene_roots)
```

Getting the following result:

```
Solutions: {α + 2*β: 1, α - 2*β: 1, α + β: 2, α - β: 2}
```

Filling the pi electrons contributed by each of the six carbons according to the [Aufbau principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle), we get:

[image]

That explains the stability of benzene, as every pi electron ends in a orbital at a energy level bellow the reference energy $\alpha$ (note $\beta$ is a negative number), and they're all paired up, thus avoiding a reactive radical form with unpaired electrons. So we find benzene and benzene-like molecules everywhere in organic chemistry. The [nucleobases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleobase) in DNA, for example, have benzene-like rings in their structures.

As explained in (2), the Huckel secular determinant can be related to the adjacency matrix of the molecular graph:

> Theorem 4. If λ is an eigenvalue and z an eigenvector of the matrix
> A, then α + βλ is an eigenvalue and z is an eigenvector of the matrix
> H.
>
> From this theorem it follows that the Hückel molecular orbitals
> coincide with the eigenvectors zj of eigenvalues λj, j=1,2,...,n, of
> the adjacency matrix of the Hückel graph. The eigenvalues λj of the
> matrix A and the energies Ej of the corresponding electrons are
> related simply as
>
> Ej = α + βλj.
>
> There are exactly n different molecular orbitals, namely the zj for
> j=1,2,...,n. This important conclusion shows that there is a deep and
> far-reaching relation between the Hückel molecular orbital theory and
> graph spectral theory. The Hückel theory provides an important field
> of application of the graph spectra. The main contribution of [9] was
> to establish that the Hückel theory and theory of graph spectra are
> essentially the same.

**References:**

(1). [Kutzelnigg, Werner. “What I like about Hückel theory”. Journal of Computational Chemistry, vol. 28, no 1, 2007, p. 25–34. Wiley Online Library, doi:https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.20470.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/jcc.20470)

(2). [Cvetkovic, Dragoš. “Two mathematical papers relevant for the Hückel molecular orbital theory”. MATCH Commun. Math. Comput. Chem, vol. 72, 2014, p. 565–72.](https://match.pmf.kg.ac.rs/electronic_versions/Match72/n2/match72n2_565-572.pdf)